# Flask on Google Compute Engine - cant reach from outside/browser

Tags: flask, port, google-compute-engine, firewall

I've setup a simple Flask server on my Compute Engine, which runs internally on 127.0.0.1:5000.

If i ssh onto that instance and curl 127.0.0.1:5000 i see the hello world message and the Flask instance shows a get in its logs.

However, if i use the external ip address through a browser it says the site doesn't exist.

I've tried to setup multiple diff firewalls, pointing to either 0.0.0.0/0 or 127.0.0.1/0 and including both tcp:5000 and udp, or just tcp or just saying allow all ports.

Nothing works.

I did try running netstat -plant and it said that port 5000 was attached to python3 (which is my Flask instance) but that the port was closed.

UPDATE:

Got it working, but will just add some more logging/output in case anyone else comes to this issue also.

`me@instance-1:~$ nmap 1.2.3.4
Starting Nmap 7.40 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-08-19 15:30 UTC
Nmap scan report for 4.3.2.1.bc.googleusercontent.com (1.2.3.4)
Host is up (0.0016s latency).
Not shown: 995 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
80/tcp   closed http
443/tcp  closed https
3389/tcp closed ms-wbt-server
5000/tcp closed upnp`

`me@instance-1:~$ netstat -plant
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29414/python3
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      1 10.142.0.2:22           118.24.87.43:51760      LAST_ACK    -
tcp        0      0 10.142.0.2:41788        169.254.169.254:80      CLOSE_WAIT  -
tcp        0      0 10.142.0.2:41796        169.254.169.254:80      ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:55258         127.0.0.1:5000          TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 10.142.0.2:41794        169.254.169.254:80      ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 10.142.0.2:22           74.125.73.96:47952      ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0    816 10.142.0.2:22           74.125.73.36:51834      ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 10.142.0.2:41792        169.254.169.254:80      ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -`

Then I restarted flask using

`flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=5000`

and now...

`me@instance-1:~$ netstat -plant
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      31365/python3
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 10.142.0.2:45802        169.254.169.254:80      ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:55258         127.0.0.1:5000          TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 10.142.0.2:41794        169.254.169.254:80      CLOSE_WAIT  -
tcp        0      0 10.142.0.2:45804        169.254.169.254:80      ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 10.142.0.2:22           74.125.73.96:47952      ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 10.142.0.2:45800        169.254.169.254:80      ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0    816 10.142.0.2:22           74.125.73.36:51834      ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
me@instance-1:~$ nmap 1.3.3.4
Starting Nmap 7.40 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-08-19 19:24 UTC
Nmap scan report for 4.3.2.1.bc.googleusercontent.com (1.2.3.4)
Host is up (0.0012s latency).
Not shown: 995 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
80/tcp   closed http
443/tcp  closed https
3389/tcp closed ms-wbt-server
5000/tcp open   upnp
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 4.75 seconds`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i assume that you are using default run method, in that provide host address as 0.0.0.0 and it will do the trick

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hi'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

This will allow you to access your website out of local-host, with ip address.

if you are using flask run method then run it as

```
flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=5000
```